# iOS not opening my https:// website SSL Certificates

Tags: php, ios, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

i developed this websites using php, html, css
https://www.joshisweetspune.com
https://www.kokansrushti.co.in
which working fine in Android and Windows
but not opening in iOS(iphone and Mac both)
it says yourconnection is not private on Chrome
and this connection is not private on Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL certificate on that site has been revoked - According to the CRL it was revoked on the 23rd of March 2019 due to "Cessation of operation"

> Serial Number: 549F2DBCB2FEBDE5
>
> Revocation Date: Mar 23 05:53:24 2019 GMT
>
> CRL entry extensions:
>
> X509v3 CRL Reason Code:
>
> Cessation Of Operation

[image]

You need to install a new, non-revoked certificate.

Edge on Windows shows that certificate as revoked.  Safari and Chrome on iOS and macOS shows the certificate as revoked. Firefox on Windows (and presumably macOS) shows the certificate as revoked.

Google has decided that the CRL process is "broken".  Therefore Chrome on Windows and Android doesn't check the CRL, so it states that the certificate is OK when it isn't.

Comment: the certificate you checked have serial number 6097642708963081701 but my new certificate has new serial number which is 7495903638236999709. please check this serial number please. thank u

Comment: The certificate that is being used by your website has serial 6097642708963081701 (hex 549F2DBCB2FEBDE5) and is revoked.  You need to install your new certificate on your site.